# D3 creating bar chart from big csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, bar-chart

I would like to create a bar chart from a csv file. The CSV file is huge and a little bit confusing, because the key columns are mostly two or three words. I am able to read the csv and get the data, such as YEAR OF ARREST. Now I need a function to count for each year the arrestees. So  I think, I need different arrays. With these arrays I would like to create a barchart, on the x-axis the years and on the y the numbers of arrestees in this year.
Can some one help me with this. I am quite new to JavaScript and it is a little bit confusing.
This is what I have so far:

```js
var arrestdate = [];

console.log(arrestdate);
d3.csv("urbana_crimes.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.map(function(m){
    arrestdate.push(m["YEAR OF ARREST"]);
  })
    //console.log(arrestdate);

    
});

console.log(arrestdate);
count(arrestdate);


function count(data) {
  data.sort();

  var current = null;
  var cnt = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i] != current) {
          if (cnt > 0) {
              document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
          }
          current = data[i];
          cnt = 1;
      } else {
          cnt++;
      }
  }
  if (cnt > 0) {
      document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times');
  }

};
```

The csv can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sg4lj2nlv5xgga7/urbana_crimes.csv?dl=0

Thanks in advance
Bernhard

EDIT:
Updated code:

```js
var arrestdate = [];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



console.log(arrestdate);
d3.csv("urbana_crimes.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.map(function(m){
    arrestdate.push(m["YEAR OF ARREST"]);
  })
  var nested = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) { return d['YEAR OF ARREST'] })
    .entries(data);
    //console.log(nested[0].key);
    //console.log(nested[0].values);
    // Set X to all your 19 keys, which are your years
    x.domain(nested.map(function(d) { return d.key }))
    // Set Y between 0 and the maximum length of values, which are your arrests
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.values.length })])

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(nested[0].values.length); }) //What to put here?
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(+nested[0].key); }) // What to put here?
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(+nested[0].key); });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group this huge data set by year first, like this:

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function (d) { return d['YEAR OF ARREST'] })
  .entries(data)
```

This gives you an array of all 19 years (accessed via `nested[0].key`) with their respective elements (accessed via `nested[0].values`). For example, 2016 has 4374 arrests so far.

[Here's a link to the d3 documentation for `d3.nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nests)

From here on you can follow any bar chart tutorial, like [Mike Bostock's example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

Set the domain of your scales like this:

```
// Set X to all your 19 keys, which are your years
x.domain(nested.map(function(d) { return d.key }))
// Set Y between 0 and the maximum length of values, which are your arrests
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.values.length })])
```

Good luck!

Edit:

I would also recommend you to either delete some information you don't need from the csv file before you load it in the browser (49 MB) or to use `map` to only extract the information you need (like you've done in your code already).

Comment: Thank you. My problem is now, that every time I load the webpage, Firefox crashes. I followed this tutorial to create a barchart http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart . My questions is: Does it even work with my data? Or do I have to create "another" barchart?

Comment: Yes, it does work with your data. [Here's a very good example from Mike Bostock, the creator of D3](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

Comment: Ok, I will try this, but I get an  "node is null error" for width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right, what is wrong with it? And for the future, do I put the nested[] in x and y domain like this: x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return nested[0].values.length; })); ?

Comment: Regarding `width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right`: Mike's example has already an `svg` element in the DOM. Your error message tells you, that `svg` is not a valid node, instead it is `null`.

Comment: @potu1304 I've added the code for the domains to my answer.

Comment: Thanks now I know what you meant. Do you mean with in the DOM to add an svg tag in the html? I have already done this. I also still get another error: d3.scaleBand is not a function.

Comment: Yes, make sure you actually have an element `svg` in your HTML tree when you do `d3.select('svg')`. If you don't have `d3.scaleBand`, then you probably use an older version of d3.js (prior to version 4.0). Make sure you load d3.js like this: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`. Unfortunately, version 4+ has a very different programming interface and many old examples won't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Our tutor said we should use the older version because himself does not know all the changes, so it is easier for him to correct it. I posted my current code in the first post. Is this correct?

Comment: Ok, then you must use version 3.x. [Here's an example with code from version 3](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219). You must use different scales (`d3.scale.linear` instead of `d3.scaleLinear` and `d3.scale.ordinal` instead of `d3.scaleBand`). Also check your debugging console in the browser, to catch all undefined or 'not a function' messages. For example, you can't use `x.bandwidth`, you must use `x.rangeBand`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, I will try it until tomorrow. It is really confusing to learn javascript and d3 in only 3 weeks. Thanks for spending time for me!

Comment: Agree, some links: [1. API reference for d3.js version 3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference), [2. Mozillas reference for JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Those two links contain 99% of all information you'll ever need. On [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/) you'll tons of examples for d3.js (beware of version 3 and 4). If you're new to JS and using d3.js prior to version 4, I can recommend Scott Murray's 'Interactive Data Visualization for the Web'. [You can read it for free online](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/). Good luck.